# Visual Studio Code Run build task in the Windows prompt with shortcut ctrl+shift+B

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, prompt

I have a C program and I need to run two batch file which manage all the compilation toolchain. The First one sets the enviroment variables and the next one to be executed performs the compilation and the linking. For some reason, eventhough I am setting all the needed enviroments variables with the first batch file, some .exe that are called by the second batch file are not recognized by the VS code internal terminal (extended error message: "file.exe" is not recognized as internal command or/and an executable program or a batch file"). I have tried to run in sequence this two batch files (by directly calling it, without any shortcut) in the Windows prompt opened in VS code and the C program is successfully compiled. Thus, Is there a way to run my build task (this batch file) in the Windows prompt opened in VS code by using the shortcut ctrl+shift+b? I have tried to set some option in the settings but they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I was calling in sequence this two batch file, namely by defining in the task.json that the compilation batch file must be executed after the other batch. But in this way, the two batch files will be executed in two different instances of the prompt, so the enviroment variable will exist only in the first prompt. That is why when the compilation batch is executed I get that problem "'file.exe' is not recognized as internal command or/and an executable program or a batch file".
In order to execute these two batch files in the same prompt it is necessary to define a task in the task.json with this command:

```
command: "batch1 && batch2",
```